# How to limit the number of "cc1plus" when using "catkin build"

Tags: ros, catkin

My computer is out-of date so when running 'catkin build' the system breakdown.

I try to limit the threads when building, by:

1. apply '-j2' at the end of catkin build
2. export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS2=-j2

But still failed.

I cheched that when running build, there are multiple "cc1plus" in when run "top".

Anyone know how to limit the number of cc1plus? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS2=-j2` is not that useful when you override with `-j2` in `catkin build`.

try calling catkin build with `-j1 -p1` to limit compiling multiple package.
in the bottom of terminal you see the number threads started to compile packages.

also I personally had better results when using workspace in `merged` instead of `linked`.